# how to add a 1 second delay using Qtimer

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I currently have a method which is as follows

```
void SomeMethod(int a)
{

     //Delay for one sec.
     timer->start(1000);

     //After one sec
     SomeOtherFunction(a);
}
```

This method is actually a slot that is attached to a signal. I would like to add a delay of one sec using Qtimer.However I am not sure on how to accomplish this. Since the timer triggers a signal when its finished and the signal would need to be attached to another method that does not take in any parameters. Any suggestion on how I could accomplish this task.?

**Update :** 
The signal will be called multiple times in a second and the delay will be for a second. My issue here is passing a parameter to the slot attached to timeout() signal of a timer.
My last approach would be to store the value in a memeber variable of a class and then use a mutex to protect it from being changed while the variable is being used .however I am looking for simpler methods here.

Comment: Do you expect to handle signals more often than the delay period?

Comment: @Linville Yes My delay would be one second and the signals might be called multiple times in a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by the way you phrase your question, but if you're asking how to get the timer's timeout() signal to call a function with a parameter, then you can create a separate slot to receive the timeout and then call the function you want. Something like this: -

```cpp
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyClass(QObject *parent);

public slots:

    void TimerHandlerFunction();
    void SomeMethod(int a);

private:
    int m_a;
    QTimer m_timer;
};
```

Implementation: -

```cpp
MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    // Connect the timer's timeout to our TimerHandlerFunction()
    connect(&m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(TimerHandlerFunction()));
}

void MyClass::SomeMethod(int a)
{
    m_a = a; // Store the value to pass later

    m_timer.setSingleShot(true); // If you only want it to fire once
    m_timer.start(1000);
}

void MyClass::TimerHandlerFunction()
{
    SomeOtherFunction(m_a);
}
```

Note that the QObject class actually has a timer that you can use by calling startTimer(), so you don't actually need to use a separate QTimer object here. It is included here to try to keep the example code close to the question.

Comment: I see you are using a member variable of a class and storing the parameter. However this is going to be multithreaded. So will this way be safe ?

Comment: I would just caveat this solution that if SomeMethod(..) is called quicker than once a second, the value of m_a will get squashed before it can be used.

Comment: It can be, depending on how you use it. If you are setting and getting the member variable in different threads, then ensure you use QMutex to lock it before setting / getting. If you're passing the value between threads, then doing this via the signal slot mechanism will ensure it's thread safe.

Comment: @Linville, very true, though without knowing the full requirements, it may not matter. If that is a problem, then the cached variable could be a QList of integers which get processed each time the TimerHandlerFunction is called.

Comment: I dont want to use a mutex in this situation. Is there a simple mechanism for this

Comment: What's your reason for not using a QMutex? All you do is create a QMutex object and call mutex.lock before you set a value and mutex.unlock afterwards? That's about as simple as it gets!

Comment: I think if I use a  QT::queuedconnection that would eliminate the need of a mutex. Do think i am right ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar asnwer is good, in addition to that, i am curios to know that. What makes you to confirm this answer is good, even your commented many queries unanswered?. I think, you misunderstood qtimer as multithreaded. Please excuse if i am wrong, and correct me.

Comment: @ashif It seems apparently that Qtimer would either require a mutex wrapped around the variable or a queued connection. I am simply using a thread now passing it the value directly. Either way the answer presented the options I had.Thanks

Answer (score 54):

Actually, there is a much more **elegant solution** to your question that doesn't require member variables or queues. With Qt 5.4 and C++11 you can [run a Lambda expression right from the `QTimer::singleShot(..)` method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot-5)! If you are using Qt 5.0 - 5.3 you can use the connect method to [connect the QTimer's timeout signal to a Lambda expression](http://woboq.com/blog/cpp11-in-qt5.html) that will call the method that needs to be delayed with the appropriate parameter.

**Edit:** With the Qt 5.4 release it's just one line of code!

**Qt 5.4 (and later)**

```
void MyClass::SomeMethod(int a) {
  QTimer::singleShot(1000, []() { SomeOtherFunction(a); } );
}
```

**Qt 5.0 - 5.3**

```
void MyClass::SomeMethod(int a) {
  QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
  timer->setSingleShot(true);

  connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=]() {
    SomeOtherFunction(a);
    timer->deleteLater();
  } );

  timer->start(1000);
}
```

Comment: This is quite nice. Too bad you can't use lambda expression with static `QTimer::singleShot()`.

Comment: @Roku, agreed! It's [QTBUG-26406](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-26406). Hopefully they'll address it soon!

Comment: Also I am not using C++11

Comment: Qt 5.4 will support [QTimer::singleShot() and lambdas](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/66110/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling `SomeMethod` multiple times per second and the delay is *always* constant, you could put the parameter `a` to a [`QQueue`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qqueue.html) and create a single shot timer for calling `SomeOtherFunction`, which gets the parameter from the `QQueue`.

```
void SomeClass::SomeMethod(int a)
{
    queue.enqueue(a);
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, this, SLOT(SomeOtherFunction()));
}

void SomeClass::SomeOtherFunction()
{
    int a = queue.dequeue();
    // do something with a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't work because `QTimer::start` is not blocking.

You should start the timer with `QTimer::singleShot` and connect it to a slot which will get executed after the QTimer times out.